# Update data using join query in mysql

Tags: mysql

The below query is working fine but not updating records in the database. In my database there is three records available for update, but it's not updating.

```
UPDATE vgm_details VD SET VD.job_id = ( select S.job_id from stuffings S JOIN vgm V ON S.booking_id = V.booking_id WHERE S.container_no = VD.container_no) where VD.job_id = 0;
```

i have attached screenshot of vgm_details table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subquery  (and related  issue for scoping) You could use an update with join

```
UPDATE vgm_details VD 
INNER JOIN  stuffings  S ON S.container_no = VD.container_no
INNER JOIN vgm V  ON S.booking_id = V.booking_id 
SET VD.job_id = S.job_id 
WHERE VD.job_id = 0;
```